# Linux shared library that uses a shared library undefined symbol

Tags: linux, gcc, shared

two shared libraries liba.so and libb.so.  liba.so uses libb.so.  All c files are compiled with -fPIC.  Linking uses -shared.  When we call dlopen on liba.so it cannot find symbols in libb.so...we get the "undefined symbol" error.  We can dlopen libb.so with no errors.  We know that liba is finding libb because we don't get a file not found error.  We get a file not found error when we delete libb.so.  We tried -lutil and no luck.

Any ideas????

oh yeah.  gcc 4.1.2

update:  We use rpath when linking liba so it can find libb.

ldd liba.so returns:

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000)  
libb.so => ./libb.so (0xf6ef9000)  <-------- LIBB 
libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0xf6ef5000)  
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf6ef1000)  
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf6ec9000)  
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6eb1000)  
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf6ea8000)  
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf6d62000)  
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x007d0000)
```

is it significat that there is no .# at the end of libb???

Comment: You are saying: you created two libs (-fPIC -shared), liba.so and libb.so. liba.so is dinamically linked (or it should be...) with libb.so and uses it. In a program X you try dlopen on libb.so and everything is ok; another test program Y tries to dlopen liba.so but it fails, nonetheless you know liba.so finds libb.so correctly since you tried to delete libb.so and another issue is raised... options you're using for dlopen?

Comment: You got it all right. Right now we use no options, because dlopen is called from some program we have no control over.

Comment: What does command `ldd liba.so` say?

Comment: ldd says libb.so => ./libb.so (0xf6ef9000) among other things.  All the other lines have an extra .# after the so name, like "libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0xf6ef5000)."  Is it significat that there is no .# after libb.so???

Comment: looks like libb.so is searched in current directory. Where do you start your application from? If it's different directory, it's normal for libb.so to not be found.

Comment: But wouldn't I get the same file not found error I get when I delete the libb.so?  We get a different error, one that suggests libb is found, but is missing the symbol.  libb is in the same dir as liba.

Comment: In this case you should check the symbol's definition - if it's defined or just declared

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can easily check where `libb.so` is expected to be with `ldd` command:

```
 $ ldd liba.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77b0000)
    libb.so.1 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb75b6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7572000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb742b000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77b1000)
```

If it's `not found`, `libb.so`'s path should be added to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Another way is setting `rpath` in the `liba.so` itself - it's basically hardcoding its path so when the binary is started the dynamic linker would know where to search for the shared libraries.

If `rpath` is not set it will first search in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then the paths mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or /etc/ld.so.conf.d/). After adding to `ls.so.conf` don't forget to execute `/sbin/ldconfig`

Dynamic linker searches the dependent shared libraries by their `soname` (if it's set) - if `soname` is not set (with -Wl,-soname,libb.so.1 for example), it will be searched by library's name.

Example: `libb.so.1.0` is your actual library, having `soname` - `libb.so.1`. You would normally have the following files structure:

```
libb.so -> libb.so.1
libb.so.1 -> libb.so.1.0
libb.so.1.0
```

where `libb.so` and `libb.so.1` are symlinks.

You usually link to `libb.so`, when building some application or other library, depending on `libb.so`.

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,liba.so.1 -o liba.so.1.2 -L/libb/path -lb
```

When the application is started (or dlopen is executed - your case)  - the dynamic linker will search for file with name `libb.so.1` - the `soname` of dependent library, if the `soname` is set, not `libb.so`.

That's why you need that symlink `libb.so.1`, pointing to the actual library.

If you use `ld.so.conf` and `ldconfig`, it will create the symlink with `soname`'s name, pointing to the library file, if this symlink is missing.

You can see [ld-linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) man page for more useful info.

---

If the library is found but some of the symbols are missing, try building `libb.so` with `-Wl,--no-undefined` option

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libb.so.1 -Wl,--no-undefined -o libb.so.1.2
```

It should give you an error if you missed to define some symbol.

Comment: we do use rpath.  We are pretty sure its finding the library, because we tried running the app after deleting libb and we get a file not found error.  When we run with libb we get an undefined symbol error.

Comment: i might not have understood the part about soname...can you clarify that a bit?

Comment: I will mess around with that and see what happens.  Also, liba uses libb.  The app calls dlopen(liba) and gets the error about a symbol used by liba that is in libb.

Comment: yes, my mistake, I confused what depends on what, it should be fixed now.

Comment: BTW, I made a presumption that libb is not found somehow, but it could just not have some of the symbols defined. See my last edit about no-undefined option.

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget that libs order (all -lxxx arguments) are important (at least in gcc) when linking all your objs & libraries to generate your executable.

Short example:

> LIBS=-L. -ltest1 -ltest2
>
> OBJS=code1.o code2.o
>
> gcc $(LIBS) $(OBJS) -o mysoft

which can fail in some cases, whereas

> gcc $(OBJS) -o mysoft $(LIBS)

won't

Comment: Hey, this answer saved my compilation.  I looked into it elsewhere and nobody else is mentioning the order of the `-o` flag (only the order of objects and libraries), although in your example you move your libs to come after `-o` as well as after the objects.  Do you know whether this ever matters?

Comment: This worked for me, but I cannot understand why though?

Comment: Because the linker searches from left to right, and notes unresolved symbols as it goes. For cyclically dependent libraries you also need to specify each libs more than once. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc