# Python throws a ModuleNotFoundError when loaded from C, but not when directly executed

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api

I'm in the process of making a module called BSPy. It's not really relevant what the module does, but its `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='BSPy', version='0.0.2', ext_modules=[Extension('BSPy', ['Interface.cpp'])])
```

Now, in order to do some debugging steps I'm using C to call a python file, and try to execute it using this bit of code:

```
#include<Python.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);
    Py_Initialize();

    FILE* PythonScriptFile = fopen("D:/- Coding/python-bsp/test.py", "r");
    if (PythonScriptFile)
    {
        PyRun_SimpleFile(PythonScriptFile, "D:/- Coding/python-bsp/test.py");
        fclose(PythonScriptFile);
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    getchar();
    return 0;
```

So far so good. I first tested a hello world file to make sure it works, and this is working wonderfully. I then went on to change the python file to use this BSPy module (which executes fine on its own and from the command line). The file now looks like this:

```
import platform
import pip  # needed to use the pip functions

print(platform.python_version())

print(sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()]))

import BSPy as bsp

print("Hello world! - from processor {} of {}.".format(bsp.pid(), bsp.nprocs()))
```

And is supposed to give the output

> ```
> 3.6.5
> ['absl-py==0.2.2', 'argh==0.26.2', 'astor==0.6.2', 'astroid==1.6.4', 'autopep8==1.3.5', 'bleach==1.5.0', 'browser-cookie3==0.6.4', 'browsercookie2==0.7.1', 'bspy==0.0.2', 'cachetools==2.1.0', 'certifi==2018.4.16', 'chardet==3.0.4', 'colorama==0.3.9', 'cycler==0.10.0', 'entrypoints==0.2.3', 'feedparser==5.2.1', 'flake8-docstrings==1.3.0', 'flake8-polyfill==1.0.2', 'flake8==3.5.0', 'future==0.16.0', 'gast==0.2.0', 'google-api-core==1.2.0', 'google-auth==1.5.0', 'google-cloud-core==0.28.1', 'google-cloud-logging==1.6.0', 'googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3', 'grpcio==1.12.0', 'gtp==0.2', 'h5py==2.8.0', 'html5lib==0.9999999', 'httplib2==0.11.3', 'idna==2.6', 'iso8601==0.1.12', 'isort==4.3.4', 'jedi==0.13.1', 'keras-applications==1.0.6', 'keras-preprocessing==1.0.5', 'keyring==10.3.2', 'kiwisolver==1.0.1', 'lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1', 'lxml==4.2.5', 'lz4==2.0.0', 'm3u8==0.3.5', 'markdown==2.6.11', 'matplotlib==2.2.2', 'mccabe==0.6.1', 'mymodule==1.0', 'numpy==1.14.3', 'oauth2client==4.1.0', 'pandas==0.23.0', 'parso==0.3.1', 'pbkdf2==1.3', 'petname==2.2', 'pillow==5.3.0', 'pip==9.0.3', 'pluggy==0.7.1', 'protobuf==3.5.2.post1', 'pyaes==1.6.1', 'pyasn1-modules==0.2.1', 'pyasn1==0.4.3', 'pybsp==0.0.1', 'pycodestyle==2.3.1', 'pycryptodome==3.6.1', 'pydocstyle==2.1.1', 'pyflakes==1.6.0', 'pylint==1.9.1', 'pyparsing==2.2.0', 'python-dateutil==2.7.3', 'python-jsonrpc-server==0.0.2', 'python-language-server==0.21.2', 'pytz==2018.4', 'pywin32-ctypes==0.1.2', 'requests==2.18.4', 'rope==0.11.0', 'rsa==3.4.2', 'setuptools==40.4.3', 'sgf==0.5', 'six==1.11.0', 'snowballstemmer==1.2.1', 'tensorboard==1.8.0', 'tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0', 'termcolor==1.1.0', 'tqdm==4.23.4', 'typed-ast==1.1.0', 'urllib3==1.22', 'virtualenv==16.1.0', 'webencodings==0.5.1', 'werkzeug==0.14.1', 'wheel==0.31.1', 'wordcloud==1.5.0', 'wrapt==1.10.11', 'yapf==0.24.0']
> Hello world! - from processor 3735928559 of 24.
> ```

However, when I try and run the C script again, it suddenly throws out a ModuleNotFoundError:

> ```
> 3.6.5
> ['absl-py==0.2.2', 'argh==0.26.2', 'astor==0.6.2', 'astroid==1.6.4', 'autopep8==1.3.5', 'bleach==1.5.0', 'browser-cookie3==0.6.4', 'browsercookie2==0.7.1', 'bspy==0.0.2', 'cachetools==2.1.0', 'certifi==2018.4.16', 'chardet==3.0.4', 'colorama==0.3.9', 'cycler==0.10.0', 'entrypoints==0.2.3', 'feedparser==5.2.1', 'flake8-docstrings==1.3.0', 'flake8-polyfill==1.0.2', 'flake8==3.5.0', 'future==0.16.0', 'gast==0.2.0', 'google-api-core==1.2.0', 'google-auth==1.5.0', 'google-cloud-core==0.28.1', 'google-cloud-logging==1.6.0', 'googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3', 'grpcio==1.12.0', 'gtp==0.2', 'h5py==2.8.0', 'html5lib==0.9999999', 'httplib2==0.11.3', 'idna==2.6', 'iso8601==0.1.12', 'isort==4.3.4', 'jedi==0.13.1', 'keras-applications==1.0.6', 'keras-preprocessing==1.0.5', 'keyring==10.3.2', 'kiwisolver==1.0.1', 'lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1', 'lxml==4.2.5', 'lz4==2.0.0', 'm3u8==0.3.5', 'markdown==2.6.11', 'matplotlib==2.2.2', 'mccabe==0.6.1', 'mymodule==1.0', 'numpy==1.14.3', 'oauth2client==4.1.0', 'pandas==0.23.0', 'parso==0.3.1', 'pbkdf2==1.3', 'petname==2.2', 'pillow==5.3.0', 'pip==9.0.3', 'pluggy==0.7.1', 'protobuf==3.5.2.post1', 'pyaes==1.6.1', 'pyasn1-modules==0.2.1', 'pyasn1==0.4.3', 'pybsp==0.0.1', 'pycodestyle==2.3.1', 'pycryptodome==3.6.1', 'pydocstyle==2.1.1', 'pyflakes==1.6.0', 'pylint==1.9.1', 'pyparsing==2.2.0', 'python-dateutil==2.7.3', 'python-jsonrpc-server==0.0.2', 'python-language-server==0.21.2', 'pytz==2018.4', 'pywin32-ctypes==0.1.2', 'requests==2.18.4', 'rope==0.11.0', 'rsa==3.4.2', 'setuptools==40.4.3', 'sgf==0.5', 'six==1.11.0', 'snowballstemmer==1.2.1', 'tensorboard==1.8.0', 'tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0', 'termcolor==1.1.0', 'tqdm==4.23.4', 'typed-ast==1.1.0', 'urllib3==1.22', 'virtualenv==16.1.0', 'webencodings==0.5.1', 'werkzeug==0.14.1', 'wheel==0.31.1', 'wordcloud==1.5.0', 'wrapt==1.10.11', 'yapf==0.24.0']
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/- Coding/python-bsp/test.py", line 8, in <module>
>     import BSPy as bsp
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BSPy'
> ```

Note that while it throws this error, pip is still confirming that BSPy is installed; hence I have no idea what could be wrong. Sadly, I can't give out a minimal working example, since the module can't be downloaded anywhere at the moment. I'm building it in this way though:

```
// Declare functions
extern "C" {
    static PyObject* init(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
    static PyObject* begin(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
    static PyObject* end(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
    static PyObject* execute(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
    static PyObject* pid(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
    static PyObject* nprocs(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
}

// Define the methods with docstrings
static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    {"init", init, METH_VARARGS, "Runs SPMD function" },
    {"begin", begin, METH_VARARGS, "Spawns an amount of processes"}, 
    {"end", end, METH_NOARGS, "Ends the processes"},
    {"execute", execute, METH_VARARGS, "Execute function"},
    {"pid", pid, METH_NOARGS, "Returns processor ID"},
    {"nprocs", nprocs, METH_NOARGS, "Returns number of processors."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

// Define the module
static struct PyModuleDef BSPy = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "BSPy",
    "A Python implementation of BSP",
    -1,
    myMethods
};


// Initialize the module
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_BSPy(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&BSPy);
}
///* Goes on to define each function. Only the simplest example is shown here.*///
static PyObject* end(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    bsp_end();
    return Py_None;
}
```

Comment: It could be that the python extension library is using a wrong version of python, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408123/python-extension-module-with-embedded-python-calls-wrong-library

Comment: @MilosMatovic I read this post. I'm on windows though, and just to be sure, I removed the 2.7 version I've got installed. Either way, it shouldn't matter though, because the same instance of python is run for each line of python code, so the pip evaluation should list the same extension library. Am I mistaken?

Comment: probably, your created exe hasn't the same python-path as the installed python. Check the output of  `import sys; print(sys.path)`  in your exe

Comment: @ead You're right. It's using python_d.exe instead of python.exe. Do you know if there's any way to force it to use the right one?