# Missing functions in Linux shared library

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I'm supporting a Linux program that allows users to write their own .so file based plugins that are loaded at runtime with dlopen(). Sometimes a user will forget to include a C++ file in the makefile that contains necessary function definitions. When the plugin manager uses dlsym() to load an exported function from the plugin that depends on one of these missing function definitions, I get a null function address.

My question: How can I detect this error ahead of time? I've tried the -z defs and -Wno-undef linker flags, but they don't generate an error. I've tried the nm, readelf, and objdump commands with various flags but the undefined functions don't show up in the symbol tables at all. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If the only references to the functions are those implicit in the use of `dlsym`, how would the linker know they’re missing?

Comment: Just terminate the main program if any of these symbols cannot be found via `dlsym`. Also, if any required symbols cannot be found in the output of `nm -D plugin.so` then the plugin is broken.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect the null function address is mostly the result of 
using some third party library in the .so file
and when the linux program does dlopen(),  it can not locate the third party  and then null function address is returned

i suggest try nm command on both "good" and "bad" .so files 
and look for the pattern of symbols with ' U ' (undefined symbol) 
"bad" .so file would have more ' U '

see also 
[Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-in-object-files)
and 
[Linux shared library that uses a shared library undefined symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991572/linux-shared-library-that-uses-a-shared-library-undefined-symbol)

Comment: The missing functions are not in a third party library. They are defined in a user created C++ file that they forgot to include in the makefile. I can't search for them using nm because the function names are not in the symbol table at all.

Answer (score 0):

`--no-undefined` / `-z defs` documentation:

> Undefined symbols
>                  in shared libraries are still allowed.

Use another flag: `--no-allow-shlib-undefined`:

> Allows or disallows undefined symbols in shared libraries.  This
>              switch is similar to `--no-undefined` except that it determines the
>              behaviour when the undefined symbols are in a shared library rather
>              than a regular object file.  It does not affect how undefined
>              symbols in regular object files are handled.